# Cross Domain POST request without using any frameworks

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

I want to make a cross domain request using script hackup in js without using any frameworks such as jquery. I want to post a json to a cross domain service and retrieve result using callback. is it possible in plain javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

The frameworks do it, so you can to. Code written by other people can't do things that code you write can't do (so long as you are willing to learn everything needed).

If you want to make a post request to a different origin then (assuming you aren't proxying the request through your own server) you have to use [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (but note [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=cors).

(For some value of "plain JavaScript" anyway, you need APIs supplied by browsers that aren't part of the core language.)

Comment: for cross domain i see a lot of materials just explaining concepts but no one providing a good tutorial. if you have any reference for cross domain POST using iframe pls share here

Comment: Don't use an iframe. Use XHR.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this.

```
var url = "http://sitename.com";
var params = "params1=value&params2=value2";
var httpc = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpc.open("POST", url, true);
httpc.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpc.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(httpc.readyState == 4 && httpc.status == 200) {
            var responseType = httpc.getAllResponseHeaders();
            if(responseType.indexOf("application/json") != -1) {
                alert(httpc.responseText);
            }
    }
}
httpc.send(params);
```

Comment: That's not a cross-browser cross-domain solution.

Comment: i am using this script for mobile app and its working for getting data from web. i dont know other script sorry.

Comment: @JDev Only for the same domain from where the script is loaded. Try changing the url (in your app) to `http://www.google.com` .. :)

Comment: This method only works if all of the following conditions are satisfied: **1.** Same origin *and* `XMLHttpRequest` level 1 is supported (IE5+6 support it through an `ActiveXObject`) or **2.** [`XMLHttpRequest` level 2 is supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2) *and* the correct [CORS response headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control#The_HTTP_response_headers) have been received. IE8 and 9 do not support XHR2, but similar functionality is implemented using [`XDomainRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573303(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this same problem today and I've come across some great tutorials on CORS.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

http://websitez.com/javascript-cross-domain-post-get/

Basically, when javascript is about to send a XMLHttpRequest request (we'll assume POST for this example) cross domain is first sends a OPTIONS request with the method and headers it wants to send in the POST request.  The remote domain should respond with appropriate headers tell your client it will accept your request.  This is called a "preflight" request.  Just remember that the same response headers need to be returned in the POST request, otherwise you'll get a 200 response code but your code will view it as an error.